# Browsing eval results in Vim Fireplace plugin

Tags: vim, clojure

how can one browse through previous form evaluation results in Fireplace? E.g., if two forms

```
(meta #'str)
(meta #'use)
```

are subsequently evaluated with ***cpp*** command, is there a possibility to have a glance at the output of these two evaluations in a Vim buffer or some sort of quickfix list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `:Last` to get the last evaluated value and `:2Last` for the one before that and so on. From the official documentation (https://github.com/tpope/vim-fireplace/blob/master/doc/fireplace.txt):

```
                                        *fireplace-:Last*
:Last           Open the result of the last evaluation in the preview
                window.  Use :2Last to get the next-to-last result,
                and so on.  Once the window is open, cycle to older
                and newer entries with |:lprevious| and |:lnext|.
```